# Center divs with text

Tags: html, css

I am running the following code:
https://jsfiddle.net/5uoz3mqz/1/

```css
.triangle {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 0 300px 300px 0;
  border-color: transparent #f08326 transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.page-title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "bebas";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(15, 138, 199, 0.87);
  border: 0.1em solid rgba(4, 79, 102, 0.22);
  width: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
  <div class="page-title">White Labs</div>
  <p>Some text here to make dasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
</div>
```

How can I center the title box as well as the text on top of the div with the triangle? I just the triangle to stay on the side and on top have the centered title box and then have the centered text.

Thanks,

Comment: Not able to understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `margin: 0pc auto;` in `.page-title`
for updated fiddle demo [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/5uoz3mqz/2/)

```
.page-title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "bebas";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(15, 138, 199, 0.87);
  border: 0.1em solid rgba(4, 79, 102, 0.22);
  width: 130px;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

Or better to give `pseudo` element instead of tringle border, 
updated code below:

```
.triangle {
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.triangle:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  right:-423px;
  top:-300px;
  background:rgba(240,131,38,0.50);
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index:0;
}
.page-title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "bebas";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(15, 138, 199, 0.87);
  border: 0.1em solid rgba(4, 79, 102, 0.22);
  width: 130px;
  margin:0px auto;
}
.triangle p {
  position: relative;
}
```

for fiddle link [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/5uoz3mqz/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply Add "margin:0 auto;" property to .page-title in css.

it will reset all margins and set it to center automatically.

Comment: .triangle {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 0 300px 300px 0;
    border-color: transparent #f08326 transparent  transparent;
    position: absolute;
}



.page-title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "bebas";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(15, 138, 199, 0.87);
  border: 0.1em solid rgba(4, 79, 102, 0.22);
  width: 130px;
margin:0 auto;

}

Comment: Still nothing. I put your code here https://jsfiddle.net/5uoz3mqz/4/ Take a look.

Comment: I haved tested it working on your jsfiddle. title gets centered. try to put the above code i have sent

Comment: Try to put width:0px and try it. You will see it wont work. Like it doesn't on my project

Comment: @carlosremove because you have give width : 0px, give it to 100%

Comment: @chirag On my project it has 100% and it shows like the result width 0px

Comment: .triangle {
    text-align: center;

    height: 0px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 0 300px 300px 0;
    border-color: transparent #f08326 transparent  transparent;
    position: absolute;
}



.page-title {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "bebas";
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(15, 138, 199, 0.87);
  border: 0.1em solid rgba(4, 79, 102, 0.22);
  width: 130px;
  margin:0 auto;

}

Comment: @carlosremove what does result width means?

Comment: @sahilahlawat The problem with that last part is that it centers without getting on top the triangle. I want it to center on the screen

Comment: @chirag I am using width so it takes the whole screen. It is for an android app

Comment: remove width : 0 px ; from .triangle property    : 
.triangle { text-align: center;  height: 0px; border-style: inset; border-width: 0 300px 300px 0; border-color: transparent #f08326 transparent transparent; position: absolute; } .page-title { position: relative; text-align: center; font-family: "bebas"; font-size: 30px; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 5px; background-color: rgba(15, 138, 199, 0.87); border: 0.1em solid rgba(4, 79, 102, 0.22); width: 130px; margin:0 auto; }

Comment: @carlosremove you want to center triangle also?

Answer (score 0):

The main div container with width:0 will be an issue , because the child container will need some width in order to position/float to center. I have changed the div structure as well, please find the solution in : https://jsfiddle.net/u1Lsux7n/1/ . Also the long text 'dssssss.......' in your example, you will have to add 'overflow' css to make such textx center aligned.

You can also have your main triangle container with a width of 90% to start and then give child containers width accordingly.

```
.triangle { 
    text-align: center; 
    width: 0px; 
    height: 0px; 
    border-style: inset; 
    border-width: 0 300px 300px 0; 
    border-color: transparent #f08326 transparent transparent; 
    position: absolute; 
}

.page-title {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center; 
    font-family: "bebas"; 
    font-size: 30px; 
    color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; 
    padding: 5px; background-color: rgba(15, 138, 199, 0.87); 
    border: 0.1em solid rgba(4, 79, 102, 0.22); 
    width: 130px; 
    margin:0 auto;

 }

 .triangle-container {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      float: left;
 }

 .page-contents {
      float: left;
 }


<div class="triangle">  
    <div class="triangle-container"> 
        <div class="page-title">Tile</div>
        <div class="page-contents">
            <p>Some text here to make dasssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</p>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```